# Calculate rolling annual returns from monthly over XTS object in R

Tags: r, xts, performanceanalytics

I have an XTS object of monthly returns across multiple columns, I'm trying to calculate rolling annual returns (geometric) for each column.

```
Date            Manager 1   Manager 2   Manager 3   Manager 4   Manager 5
20160430        0.0152000   0.0100700   0.0102210   0.0046160   NA
20160531        0.0462000   0.0515240   0.0287490   0.0374920   NA
20160630        0.0007000   0.0126830   0.0156410   0.0130820   NA
20160731        0.0200000   0.0158810   0.0239540   0.0214950   NA
20160831        0.0339000   0.0531980   0.0021170   0.0476160   0.0457650
20160930        -0.0071000  0.0047540   -0.0088080  0.0031540   -0.0034070
20161031        -0.0224000  -0.0181930  0.0181410   -0.0048280  0.0170850
20161130        -0.0439000  -0.0131600  -0.0243030  -0.0064650  -0.0007180
20161231        -0.0051000  0.0200130   0.0204210   0.0160740   0.0172270
20170131        0.0083000   0.0146560   0.0247000   0.0203410   0.0227060
20170228        0.0211000   -0.0067120  0.0257530   0.0029940   0.0124730
20170331        0.0530000   0.0532190   0.0283950   0.0416190   0.0237900
20170430        0.0638300   0.0592280   0.0341340   0.0437430   0.0293500
20170531        0.0339000   0.0264270   0.0287670   0.0207810   0.0179080
20170630        NA          -0.0046950  -0.0091310  -0.0074520  -0.0137600
20170731        NA          0.0109280   0.0029630   0.0146560   0.0167990
20170831        NA          0.0290430   0.0372960   0.0284390   0.0229930
20170930        NA          0.0226390   0.0030190   0.0063850   -0.0087170
```

Exepcted Results:

```
Date            Manager 1   Manager 2   Manager 3   Manager 4   Manager 5                       
20160430                        
20160531                        
20160630                        
20160731                        
20160831                        
20160930                        
20161031                        
20161130                        
20161231                        
20170131                        
20170228                        
20170331        0.121979182 0.212964432 0.176317288 0.213932804 
20170430        0.175724107 0.271996881 0.204161963 0.261212111 
20170531        0.161901314 0.241637796 0.204183032 0.240897626 
20170630                    0.220330851 0.174812396 0.215746067 
20170731                    0.214381041 0.150728807 0.207606539 0.200188843
20170831                    0.186529323 0.191124778 0.185500853 0.174054195
20170930                    0.207649992 0.205337395 0.189319163 0.167798654
```

I've been using the PerformanceAnalytics package, but having some trouble applying the function across each column:

```
apply.rolling(ManagerReturns, width = 12, trim = FALSE ,FUN = Return.annualized)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply.rolling` is a wrapper around `rollapply`. For some reason `apply.rolling` doesn't work correctly with your data, but using rollapply will solve the issue.

using `rollapply` I can get close to your outcome, with a but. The but is that the Return.annualized removes the NA values but continues to calculate. You can see this happening with Manager1 and Manager5. This is not because rollapply, but because of `Return.annualized`. For example `Return.annualized(my_data$Manager5[1:12])` returns an annualized return of 0.2207884.

```
ra <- rollapply(my_data, width = 12, FUN = Return.annualized, fill = 0)     

            Manager1  Manager2  Manager3  Manager4  Manager5
2016-04-30 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-05-31 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-06-30 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-07-31 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-08-31 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-09-30 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-10-31 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-11-30 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2016-12-31 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2017-01-31 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2017-02-28 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
2017-03-31 0.1219792 0.2129644 0.1763173 0.2139328 0.2207884
2017-04-30 0.1757241 0.2719969 0.2041620 0.2612121 0.2409790
2017-05-31 0.1619013 0.2416378 0.2041830 0.2408976 0.2406184
2017-06-30 0.1769613 0.2203309 0.1748124 0.2157461 0.1982881
2017-07-31 0.1682027 0.2143810 0.1507288 0.2076065 0.2001888
2017-08-31 0.1368823 0.1865293 0.1911248 0.1855009 0.1740542
2017-09-30 0.1676742 0.2076500 0.2053374 0.1893192 0.1677987
```

Now you could do something like `ra * !is.na(my_data)` which will multiply `ra` with a 0 in case of NA's and will remove the last 4 records of Manager1. But it will not help with Manager5.

data:

```
my_data <- structure(c(0.0152, 0.0462, 7e-04, 0.02, 0.0339, -0.0071, -0.0224, 
-0.0439, -0.0051, 0.0083, 0.0211, 0.053, 0.06383, 0.0339, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.01007, 0.051524, 0.012683, 0.015881, 0.053198, 
0.004754, -0.018193, -0.01316, 0.020013, 0.014656, -0.006712, 
0.053219, 0.059228, 0.026427, -0.004695, 0.010928, 0.029043, 
0.022639, 0.010221, 0.028749, 0.015641, 0.023954, 0.002117, -0.008808, 
0.018141, -0.024303, 0.020421, 0.0247, 0.025753, 0.028395, 0.034134, 
0.028767, -0.009131, 0.002963, 0.037296, 0.003019, 0.004616, 
0.037492, 0.013082, 0.021495, 0.047616, 0.003154, -0.004828, 
-0.006465, 0.016074, 0.020341, 0.002994, 0.041619, 0.043743, 
0.020781, -0.007452, 0.014656, 0.028439, 0.006385, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.045765, -0.003407, 0.017085, -0.000718, 0.017227, 0.022706, 
0.012473, 0.02379, 0.02935, 0.017908, -0.01376, 0.016799, 0.022993, 
-0.008717), .Dim = c(18L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Manager1", 
"Manager2", "Manager3", "Manager4", "Manager5")), index = structure(c(1461974400, 
1464652800, 1467244800, 1469923200, 1472601600, 1475193600, 1477872000, 
1480464000, 1483142400, 1485820800, 1488240000, 1490918400, 1493510400, 
1496188800, 1498780800, 1501459200, 1504137600, 1506729600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")
```